# Alias multiple names in the same line

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to `alias` several Models in the same file and it's taking a lot of visible space in my file when doing it as usual:

```
alias Project.Model1
alias Project.Model2
...
alias Project.ModelN
```

I looked into the docs and I don't think it's possible to do it like this:

```
alias (Project.Model1, Project.Model2,...,Project.ModelN)
```

Do I need to do it like this:

```
alias Project.Model1 alias Project.Model2 ... alias Project.ModelN
```

Or is there an alternative?

Comment: `alias Project.{Model1, Model2, ..., ModelN}` should work.

Comment: @arpit great, thanks for sharing. Is there any reference to this `{}` feature (I guess it might work whereever?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use curly braces to do that:

```
alias Project.{Model1,Model2,Model3}
```

Also see [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#alias/2) and [getting started guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#multi-aliasimportrequireuse).

Comment: Great. But I don't think that is reflected in the docs...is it? Do you think it would be good to open an issue?

Comment: Yeah it seems to be missing, good idea opening an issue! It would be nice if you could link back to the issue here for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer to the answer by @patrick-oscity for this particular task**.

[`Kernel.alias/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#alias/2) is a macro, accepting two parameters: module and [optional] `Keyword` having a key `as`: `[as: ...]`.

So, the simple answer to your question is “you can’t.”

Why would you entangle your code’s future readers? Please use the Elixir style guide and just stick with 1 alias per 1 line.

---

**UPD** While you still want to list all aliases in one line, define your own macro:

```
defmacro aliases(macros) when is_list(macros) do
  for macro <- macros do
    quote do
      alias unquote(macro)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, I really think Elixir is a top language and agree with all of it except for a few bits. In this particular I think that taking the most of my screen real state worths more than super clean code. My goal is to see the maximum of code logic in just one screen without the need to be scrolling up and down to get it. And as `alias` is a super simple concept with no chances for mistakes when you don't use `as:` I'm convinced that this could be valuable.

Comment: Then please use Elixir’s power and declare your own macro `defmacro aliases` accepting a plain list and producing a bundle of `alias` macros :)

Comment: According to best practices what would be the best file to define such macros?